# Why does boost::shared_ptr use gcc inline assembly to increase use_count instead of using operator++?

Tags: c++, boost, thread-safety, shared-ptr, atomic

I'm reading `boost::shared_ptr` source code and found it using this function to increase shared_ptr's use count(reference count):

```
inline void atomic_increment( int * pw )
{
    //atomic_exchange_and_add( pw, 1 );

    __asm__
    (
        "lock\n\t"
        "incl %0":
        "=m"( *pw ): // output (%0)
        "m"( *pw ): // input (%1)
        "cc" // clobbers
    );
}
```

Why not simply use the `operator++` to do this? Does this give better performance?

Comment: Maybe because `operator++` is not atomic?

Comment: To be more specific, because `++` won't include the `lock` prefix that's used in that assembly code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ++ operator reads it's operand's current value, adds 1 and writes the result back. This can be three interruptible (i.e., by another thread) steps. If two threads do this at the same time it is possible that the result is wrong. To protect against this one must use atomic operations or locks. This is done by the asm code shown above.

Comment: Now, in C++0x, they should use std::atomic<int> and std::atomic_address instead of the assembly code.

Comment: In C++11, you should use std::shared_ptr instead of boost::shared_ptr

Comment: "_This can be three interruptible (i.e., by another thread) steps._" what do you mean by interruptible? Almost no CPU instruction is interruptible. Do you think that any compiler will not generate a single (non-interruptible) load, a single (non-interruptible) incr, a single (non-interruptible) store for `++`?

Comment: @curiousguy: Why do you think instructions such as load and store are uninterruptible? What I meant in my post was that it is possible that thread A loads the operand in a register, gets interrupted by thread B , thread B then performs the load, inc, store sequence, hence writing op+1 to memory, thread A regains control an performs inc, store, therefore also writing op+1.

Comment: @timos "_Why do you think instructions such as load and store are uninterruptible?_" Do you know a single CPU where they are interruptible? "_it is possible that thread A loads the operand in a register, gets interrupted by thread B , thread B then performs the load, inc, store sequence, hence writing op+1 to memory, thread A regains control an performs inc, store, therefore also writing op+1._" So no instruction is interruptible, but the read-modify-write sequence of 3 instructions is interruptible and not atomic. Anyway, uninterruptible does not imply atomic. You are mixing concepts here.

Comment: An interruptible CPU instruction is an instruction which can takes very long, so the CPU may handle an interrupt during the execution of the instruction. The only example I know is the old loop instructions on x86.

Comment: @curiousguy That's not true, at least on any modern (i.e., Pentium) x86 CPU which employs pipelining any instruction can be interrupted, especially load/store instructions, they can take very long compared to arithmetic instructions. That's why caches have been introduced. If you want more information about such topics I recommend Hennessy/ Pattersons book on Computer Architecture.

Comment: @timos Does this book say that (correctly aligned) load/store instructions are interruptible?

Comment: @curiousguy This has nothing to do with alignment. So yes.

Comment: @timos "_This has nothing to do with alignment._" Hug? What is an interruptible instruction?

Comment: This discussion has very little to do with the original question, you should maybe open a new thread.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ standard does not guarantee the i++ or ++i operations to be atomic. So depending on compiler it may or may not be atomic. This workaround  uses assembly language to get around this limitation.
Now, the C++ standard includes  `std::atomic<T>` that guarantees the operations on the object to be atomic.